# Inserting popup menu to explorer context menu in c#

Tags: c#-2.0

I have a requirement where in I need to add a Context menu Item say "Tasks" and when I point my mouse over it, it should show a popup menu with the lists of tasks that are to be performed with that file/folder. Just like when you right click on a folder on desktop and you point at it, say "Send To" it shows the options.

Am able to add "Tasks" in to the context menu and my code is:

```
RegistryKey rKey = Registry.ClassesRoot.OpenSubKey(@"Directory\shell", true);

RegistryKey newKey = rKey.CreateSubKey("Harsha");
RegistryKey newSubKey = newKey.CreateSubKey("command");
newSubKey.SetValue("", @"C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\C Sharp\Chat Program\TestContext\TestContext\bin\Debug\TestContext.exe " + "\"" + "%1" + "\"");
newSubKey.Close();
newKey.Close();
rKey.Close();
```

In TestContext.cs am just displaying the file/folder path I selected for now. This path will be later used for further processing.

```
static void Main(string[] arguments)
{
    string folderpath = string.Empty;
    if (arguments.Length > 0)
    {
        folderpath = arguments[0];
        MessageBox.Show(folderpath, "Test Application", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.None);

    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("You need to select a folder to continue.", "Test Application", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }
}
```

Now, I want to add the sub-menu with task options to "Tasks". And when I select an option, how will I know which option was selected?
 Can I please know how to do it?
Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: This requires a shell extension.  Writing those in C# is strongly discouraged, injecting the CLR into Windows Explorer is not sustainable.  And should never be attempted with such an old version of .NET.

Comment: I have a C++ code that does this, am asked to implement the same in C#.

Comment: Keep the C++ code.  Don't do this in C#.